# How to extract items from a template(at eSignature Api)

Tags: docusignapi

I made a template.and added an item.(text input)

I looked at the sample and tried to use the field item extraction function, but no result.

I want to know how to extract field items. at the eSignature api

I added a capture image

```
    String templateId = "45deb3ff-6054-4316-bd4d-a3cee82ff527";
    TemplatesApi templateApi = new TemplatesApi();
    EnvelopeTemplate envelopeTemplate;
    try {
        envelopeTemplate = templateApi.get(accountId, templateId);  

        List<Document> documentList = envelopeTemplate.getDocuments();

        Document document = documentList.get(0);

        String documentId = document.getDocumentId();

        DocumentFieldsInformation dfi = templateApi.listDocumentFields(accountId, templateId, documentId);
        CustomFields cf= templateApi.listCustomFields(accountId, templateId);
        List<TextCustomField> lcf = cf.getTextCustomFields();   

        for(int i = 0; i < lcf.size(); i++) {
            TextCustomField aaa = lcf.get(i);
        }

        List<NameValue> nv = dfi.getDocumentFields(); 
        Iterator<NameValue> i = nv.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()) {    
            NameValue nv2 = i.next();
            String name = nv2.getName();
            String value = nv2.getValue();
            nv2.setValue("test");
        }
    } catch (ApiException e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

Do you want to know the tab (field) values of an envelope after it has been completed and signed?

If so, use API method [EnvelopeFormData::get](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeFormData/get)

Here is an [example for PHP](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant/blob/master/src/EG015EnvelopeTabData.php).

If your question is about something else, then please **edit** your question to add more information on what you are trying to do.